# Use jquery IF statement for two different IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

this is probably dead simple but I just can find a solution myself. I have this code:

```
      $('article li.active').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'arrival-and-departure') {
          $('p.quot').hide();
        }
        else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'additional-needs') {
          $('p.quot').hide();
        }
        else {$('p.quot').show()}
      };
```

I was wondering how I could combine the two IFs so that I just need IF and Else. Any help would be very welcome, thanks!

Comment: you should use OR in you first if statement `if v1 == "test" || v1 =="other"){...}`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('article li.active').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'arrival-and-departure' || $(this).attr('id') === 'additional-needs') {
        $('p.quot').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('p.quot').show();
    }
});
```

The double-pipe operator acts as an "OR" operator. So check if it's "this" OR "that".

Answer (score 2):

You should use OR:

```
$('article li.active').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'arrival-and-departure' || 
        $(this).attr('id') == 'additional-needs') 
    {
      $('p.quot').hide();
    }
    else {$('p.quot').show()}
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use && (and) and || (or)

```
var a = true;
var b = false;
var c = true;
if(a&&b) //false since b=false, only a=true
if(a&&c) //true since a&c are both true
if(a||b)//a=true so>will be true. Javascript even won't check B (keep in mind when using functions!
```

More here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [switch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) instead of the `if` with the `||` operator, like this:

```
$('article li.active').each(function() {
    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'arrival-and-departure':
        case 'additional-needs':
            $('p.quot').hide();
            break;
        default:
            $('p.quot').show();
    }
});
```